# Angular Js Loading data for Chart

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create charts( Using Chart.js Lib ) using ng-repeat.

EDIT : [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/DAUkixDSOvjBKGhYjAu3?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<div class="graph-display" ng-controller="jsonServerBox">
<div class="bar-chart-box" ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules"> 
  <canvas class="chart chart-bar" data="{{module.data}}" labels="{{module.labels}}" series="{{module.series}}"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('jsonServerBox', function($scope, $http) {
  var json = {"modules":[
                {
                   "series":"SeriesA",
                   "data":["90", "99", "80", "91", "76", "75", "60", "67", "59", "55"],
                   "labels":["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07","08","09","10"]
                },

                {
                   "series":"SeriesB",
                   "data":["90", "99", "80", "91", "76", "75", "60", "67", "59", "55"],
                   "labels":["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07","08","09","10"]
                }

        ]}; 
    $scope.ocw = json;
    });
```

And I'm getting following error:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'module.data' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{module.data}}] starting at [module.data}}].
```

Please help.

Comment: `data="{{module.data}}"` this will evaluate as `data="{"modules": [ {...}]}" ` double quote inside double quote wont work on html, you should use isolated scope inside your directive by doing `scope: { data: '='}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign scope variables directly from View like `data="module.data" labels="module.labels" series="module.series"`.

Don't use interpolution directive while providing data & lables to directive. Because the [chart.js](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) implementation is based on isolated scope

**HTML**

```
<div class="graph-display" ng-controller="jsonServerBox">
<div class="bar-chart-box" ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules"> 
  <canvas class="chart chart-bar" data="module.data" labels="module.labels" series="{{module.series}}"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
```

This could help you. Thanks.

**Update 1:**

Actually you were missed couple of thing.

```
"series": ["SeriesA"],
"data": [["90", "99", "80", "91", "76", "75", "60", "67", "59", "55"]],
```

Changes in your code are

1. Wrap Series inside array changed `"series": "SeriesA"`, to `"series": ["SeriesA"]`
2. Wrap data array inside array because it takes dimensional array as an input.

Check [**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/o6nSTD5tPRTRuOLgPXck?p=preview) for more info.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi I have updated my question with a plunker. Please have a look.