# Load JSON to display data, using ng-repeat {ANGULAR.JS}

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

My Html:

```
<div class="graph-display" ng-controller="jsonServerBox">
    <div class="bar-chart-box" ng-repeat="module in ocw.modules"> 
        <canvas class="chart chart-bar" data="{{module.data}}" labels="{{module.labels}}" series="{{module.series}}"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
app.controller('jsonServerBox', function($scope, $http) {
  var json = $http.get('serverbox.json').then(function(res){
          return res.data;
        });
  $scope.ocw = json;    
    });
```

The Chart doesn't gets displayed, don't know why? I'm not getting any error in console either.

UPDATE: MY JSON FILES CONTENT

```
[{"modules":[
            {
               "series":"SeriesA",
               "data":["90", "99", "80", "91", "76", "75", "60", "67", "59", "55"],
               "labels":["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07","08","09","10"]
            },

            {
               "series":"SeriesB",
               "data":["90", "99", "80", "91", "76", "75", "60", "67", "59", "55"],
               "labels":["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07","08","09","10"]
            }

    ]}
]
```

CONSOLE LOG:

```
modules: Array[2]0: Objectdata: Array[10]0: "90"1: "99"2: "80"3: "91"4: "76"5: "75"6: "60"7: "67"8: "59"9: "55"length: 10__proto__: Array[0]labels: Array[10]0: "01"1: "02"2: "03"3: "04"4: "05"5: "06"6: "07"7: "08"8: "09"9: "10"length: 10__proto__: Array[0]series: "SeriesA"__proto__: Object1: Objectdata: Array[10]0: "90"1: "99"2: "80"3: "91"4: "76"5: "75"6: "60"7: "67"8: "59"9: "55"length: 10__proto__: Array[0]labels: Array[10]0: "01"1: "02"2: "03"3: "04"4: "05"5: "06"6: "07"7: "08"8: "09"9: "10"length: 10__proto__: Array[0]series: "SeriesB"
```

Comment: could you bring it in fiddle ?

Comment: It's not showing up because you are getting the data after the chart renders. So you need something to update the chart once the data actually loads in. I'm assuming the chart is some sort of library, so the normal angular $digest will not update the variables you give to the chart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `json` is Promise object not the data returned from AJAX call. Also your question has "returning from AJAX request" aspect. Make sure you understand related problem, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) very popular question.

Proper way to set scope data retrieved with AJAX request in Angular is to do it inside then callback:

```
app.controller('jsonServerBox', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('serverbox.json').then(function (res) {
        $scope.ocw = res.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, But still chart is not getting rendered. May be there's some issue in my JSON DATA FORMAT. Posting it in my Question. PLease have a look.

Comment: Put `{{ocw}}` below canvas and see if it gets populated. If so, then the problem is with chart library which doesn't update when data changes.

Comment: Sure will try, I have tested the chart library and its working fine.

Comment: Not sure but looks like your data should be one dimensional array?

Comment: Nope putting {{ocw}} below canvas doesn't gets it populated.

Comment: Then check the structure of `console.log(res)` inside `then`. Does it have `data` property?

Comment: Done that, posted the console log.

Answer (score 4):

In you case `json` variable is nothing but it contains **[promise](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/)** object.

And Promise should always be resolve using `.then`

**CODE**

```
var json = $http.get('serverbox.json').then(function(res) {
    return res.data;
});
json.then(
  //success callback
  function(data) {
      $scope.ocw = data
  },
  //error callback
  function() {
      //error handling
  })
});
```

This would help you.

Thanks.

Comment: @sanki Why there is array inside array `"data":[["90", "99", "80", "91", "76", "75", "60", "67", "59", "55"]],` ? single array should be fine enough like `"data":[["90", "99", "80", "91", "76", "75", "60", "67", "59", "55"]`..

Comment: @sanki  If you want, you can accept my this answer too, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278096/angular-js-loading-data-for-chart/28278459#28278459 issue has been resolved for json

Comment: @sanki Thats cool thing..let me know once you update your question..Thanks

Comment: @sanki I've heard that you are going to raise bounty for it :p