# How to change colours for Angular-Chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, bar-chart, chart.js

I use Angular-Chart.js (the AngularJS [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) version) to create a bar chart. The Chart is working with the options except for the colours.

Even if I set them it is indicated [in the documentation](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#bar-chart), they stay grey.

```
<div class="graph-display" ng-controller="chartController">
    <canvas class="chart chart-bar"
    data="bilans.data"
    labels="bilans.labels"
    series="bilans.series"
    options="{
        scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
        scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
        tooltipTemplate: '<%= value %> $',
        responsive: true
    }"
    colours="{
    fillColor: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
    strokeColor: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
    highlightFill: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
    highlightStroke: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)'
    }"
    ></canvas>
</div>
```

Actually, the options are working but the colours are not. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your should declare `colours` object as an array

```
"colours": [{
    fillColor: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
    strokeColor: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
    highlightFill: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)',
    highlightStroke: 'rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)'
}];
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SYgfQTTEC2XD1OA0ZReV?p=preview)

For more info refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278178/load-json-to-display-data-using-ng-repeat/28278331#28278331) / [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278096/angular-js-loading-data-for-chart/28278459#28278459) too.

---

For newer versions, see [eli0tt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40282914/59087), as the parameter names have changed.

Comment: Mind the 'u' I had "colors" starting out

Comment: @Dashu could you checkout the directive https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/blob/master/angular-chart.js#L19

Comment: highliftFill and highlightStroke have been changed and you need to add point infront of both of those. In addition you have to add "pointColor" to get the color on hover ;)

Comment: @PankajParkar can you see please my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37056480/how-can-i-get-a-chart-from-a-matrix

Comment: @PankajParkar please can you see my question maybe you have an idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256487/i-want-to-change-the-chart-for-each-city-or-subcity-selected

Comment: FYI I have found some versions of this to use the name "colour" and others "color". At time of writing it contradicted the spelling used in the documentation.

Comment: What version is this Plunkr using? I can't get running with the current angular-chart.js

Comment: Can you put plunkr here? I'll help you to make it running

Answer (score 13):

I was having the same difficulty. In the docs it says to use "colors" however once I updated my html to:

`chart-colours`

with an angular array of:

`$scope.colours = ['#72C02C', '#3498DB', '#717984', '#F1C40F'];`

It worked!

Comment: for reference, angular-chart.js has changed naming from colours to colors
'chart-colours is now chart-colors and chart-get-colour is now chart-get-color' 
https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/tree/1.0.0

Answer (score 8):

It seems that naming changed again. I'm using **angular-chart.js 1.0.3** and color management for bar charts works like this :

```
colors:[{
      backgroundColor:"#F00",
      hoverBackgroundColor:"#FF0",
      borderColor:"#0F0",
      hoverBorderColor:"#00F"
}];
```

In the canvas tag, the name of the attribute is **chart-colors**

Answer (score 7):

As @pankajparkar said. Just adding that you can also pass html colours and angular-chart.js will define the colour objects properly in rgba with the proper nuances e.g. `$scope.colors = ['#FD1F5E','#1EF9A1','#7FFD1F','#68F000'];`

Answer (score 6):

As at 2017 I got angular-charts to work with the following code.

1. that the names of the elements are changed. Taken from the angular-chart source code.
2. also that as soon as you run out of colours angular-chart will generate them for you. This includes an opacity of 0.2 for background colours.
3. If you specify #hex colours opacity will be added.

Colour specification via global.

```
app.config(['ChartJsProvider', function (ChartJsProvider) {

// Using ChartJsProvider.setOptions('bar', { didn't seem to work for me.
// Nor did $scope.chartColors. Although I only tried that in the controller.
Chart.defaults.global.colors = [
  {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(78, 180, 189, 1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(78, 180, 189, 1)',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)'
  }, {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(229, 229, 229, 1)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(229, 229, 229, 1)',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)'
  }
...
```

In the source code the colour picking code is currently. Colours set via Chart.js options are reset here (I didn't get this to work).

Pick colours as per angular-chart.js source code:

```
  var colors = angular.copy(scope.chartColors ||
    ChartJs.getOptions(type).chartColors ||
    Chart.defaults.global.colors
```

Yes, if you don't specify an object, opacity is set for you. From angular-chart.js:

```
function convertColor (color) {
  if (typeof color === 'object' && color !== null) return color;
  if (typeof color === 'string' && color[0] === '#') return getColor(hexToRgb(color.substr(1)));
  return getRandomColor();
}
...
function getColor (color) {
  return {
    backgroundColor: rgba(color, 0.2),
    pointBackgroundColor: rgba(color, 1),
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: rgba(color, 0.8),
    borderColor: rgba(color, 1),
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: rgba(color, 1)
  };
}
```

Comment: you sir, deserve a cookie. Thanks for your excelent explanation it solved my problem and ended two hours of searching!

Comment: Thanks very much, the angularjs chartjs website is outdated

Answer (score 2):

You wanted to say: "colours"

```
$scope.colours = ['#FD1F5E','#1EF9A1','#7FFD1F','#68F000'];
```

Also we can see the other attributes That we can change , like : legend , series, hover . Next to each chart you can see an option called "settings ", that's all what you can change.

Comment: for reference, angular-chart.js has changed naming from colours to colors
'chart-colours is now chart-colors and chart-get-colour is now chart-get-color' 
https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/tree/1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version $scope.colors does not seem to work. You need to use **`chart-dataset-override="colors"`**

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("DoughnutCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.results = {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0, '9': 0, '10': 0};
  $scope.labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'];
  
  $scope.data = [
    [1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 33, 5]
  ];
  $scope.colors = [{ 
    fillColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,0.2)',
    strokeColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,1)',
    pointColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,1)',
    pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
    pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
    pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,0.8)'
  }];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multi Slot Transclude</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.0.3/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="DoughnutCtrl">
  <canvas
        class="chart chart-bar"
        chart-data="data"
        chart-labels="labels"
        chart-dataset-override="colors">
      </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this one not working in my case.i want to set 3 fixed color in bar chart