# How to change the color of the labels using Angular Charts

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need the labels for the bar graph to be a different color. Everything works just need the labels to be white rather than the default grey.

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar whiteFont"
    chart-data="ageData" chart-labels="ageLabels"
    colours="colours">
</canvas>
```

Comment: can you share your snippet in plunkr or some where else?

Answer (score 1):

Defer your `colours` as an array. For more information u can see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647492/how-to-change-colours-for-angular-chart-js)

Comment: It doesn't look like that solution works for labels like the OP is asking for