# ChartJS - Override Attributes (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js

I have simple chartjs in angularjs, and I would like override a few options like borderWidth, backgroundColor and so on ...

[image]

I've tried ...

## HTML

```
<div ng-app="chartDemo" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
      <canvas id="doughnut" class="chart chart-doughnut"
        chart-data="mainCtrl.data" chart-labels="mainCtrl.labels" chart-options="mainCtrl.options" chart-dataset-override="mainCtrl.datasetOverride">
      </canvas>
</div>
```

## JS

```
angular.module('chartDemo', ['chart.js'])
    .config(['ChartJsProvider', function (ChartJsProvider) {
    // Configure all charts
    ChartJsProvider.setOptions({
      //animation: false,
      //responsive: false
    });
  }])
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope, $timeout) {
  var chart = this;
  
  chart.labels = ["Stack", "Over", "Flow"];
  chart.data = [10, 30, 70];
  chart.options = {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    cutoutPercentage: 60,
    tooltipEvents: [],
    tooltipCaretSize: 0,
    showTooltips: true,
    onAnimationComplete: function() {
      self.showTooltip(self.segments, true);
    }
  }
 
/*   chart.datasetOverride = [{borderWidth: 2 }, {borderWidth: 5 },{borderWidth: 10 } ]; */
  
  
 /*  chart.datasetOverride = [{hoverBackgroundColor: '#ff6384' }, {hoverBackgroundColor: '#45b7cd' },{hoverBackgroundColor: '#ff8e72' } ]; */
  
  
  chart.datasetOverride = [{backgroundColor: '#ccc' }, {backgroundColor: '#ddd' },{backgroundColor: '#fff' } ];
  
  
 
}

MainController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];
```

I've tried look everywhere in their documentation (https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/), but see nothing to do that.

Any sugesstion for me to get that working ?

## Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/csupfywt/

Answer (score 4):

Refer to the source code:

```
function getChartData (type, scope) {
  var colors = getColors(type, scope);
  return Array.isArray(scope.chartData[0]) ?
    getDataSets(scope.chartLabels, scope.chartData, scope.chartSeries || [], colors, scope.chartDatasetOverride) :
    getData(scope.chartLabels, scope.chartData, colors, scope.chartDatasetOverride);
}
...
function getData (labels, data, colors, datasetOverride) {
  var dataset = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: colors.map(function (color) {
        return color.pointBackgroundColor;
      }),
      hoverBackgroundColor: colors.map(function (color) {
        return color.backgroundColor;
      })
    }]
  };
  if (datasetOverride) {
    angular.merge(dataset.datasets[0], datasetOverride);
  }
  return dataset;
}
```

So if your `data` is just an array of number, `datasetOverride` should be an object instead of array:

```
chart.datasetOverride = {
  borderWidth: 10, 
  backgroundColor: ["#f00", "#00f", "#000"],
  hoverBackgroundColor: ["#f0f", "#0ff", "#ff0"]
};
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oaxz15n7/)

**Note:** For colors only, you can pass an array of objects represent color to `chart-colors` but it's strange that they take `pointBackgroundColor` as `backgroundColor` and `backgroundColor` as `hoverBackgroundColor`:

```
chart.colors = [
  {
    backgroundColor: "#0f0",
    pointBackgroundColor: "#000",
  },
  {
    backgroundColor: "#f0f",
    pointBackgroundColor: "#00f",
  },
  {
    backgroundColor: "#ff0",
    pointBackgroundColor: "#f00",
  },
];
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oaxz15n7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
  chart.datasetOverride = [
    {fillColor: '#ccc' }, 
    {strokeColor: '#ddd' },
    {highlightFill: '#fff' } 
  ];
```

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28647813/1772933

Comment: Can you please try your answer it base on my fiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for how to override default chart colors:

Under ChartJsProvider.setOptions, simply add

> chartColors: ['#000', '#0000ff', '#ee82ee']

Note: Be mindful of what color types you use e.g (HEX or RGBA), this option only works for HEX colors

See below for reference:

```
angular.module('chartDemo', ['chart.js'])
    .config(['ChartJsProvider', function (ChartJsProvider) {
    // Configure all charts
    ChartJsProvider.setOptions({
    chartColors: ['#000', '#0000ff', '#ee82ee'],
      //animation: false,
      //responsive: false
    });
  }])
    .controller('MainController', MainController);
```

For a working Fiddle example, see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sirleon/mtuqfcs3/3/)

For further reading, check out angular-chart.js documentation [here](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js)

Comment: @cyb3rZ try this and check out the fiddle, hope it helps